# make a sort of two ArrayList if an element change a position the second one of the other arraylist change also the position

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working with java and I need some ideas , I have two arraylists `lis1` and `lis2`. The first one contains elements

`lis1[a,b,c,d]`

and the second one

```
lis2[a',b',c',d']
```

If I make a sort to my first list `lis1` for example 
    `lis1[b,c,a,d]` I want the second one to become `lis2[b',c',a',d']`. I need some help on it just an idea.

Comment: I would use a list of `Comparable` objects which contain all the information in both lists. This can be sorted with `Collections.sort()`

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that you have *one* list here, populated with objects each containing a and a', b and b' etc.

e.g. something like `List<Pair>`

where `Pair` is an object containing your two elements. You can then write a comparator for `Pair` which simply compares between the first element of each `Pair` object.

I wouldn't use two lists here. You have to keep them in sync, and this seems fragile at best.

Answer (score 1):

One way may be, Write your own [comparator](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html) with required sorting logic. Apply same comparator on both list while sorting.